# How can I remotely reset a circuit breaker with obstructed access?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a 42 foot Rv in a resort. When they put in the RV they covered the 30 amp breaker box and now if the breaker goes I have to crawl under the trailer to get to the box. Is there a way to run a wire from the 30 amp breaker box to inside the RV that if it blows I can switch it back on inside the RV?

Comment: move one or the other.

Comment: How did they cover the box?  If three is some sort of problem, you really need to get to that box. It needs to be accessible.  Can the RV be moved?

Answer (score 5):

You really need to move the location of the box or the trailer over enough to make it accessible. By code 0-150v to ground requires 36” so the box needs to be moved or the trailer moved over, see NEC 110.26(A)(1) for details.

Answer (score 4):

Yup, affirming what Ed Beal says+, Code *absolutely requires* a [clear working space around every service panel](https://inspectapedia.com/electric/Electrical-Panel-Clearance-Distances.php), *all the time*.  You can't block it with an RV, *you can't even store stuff there*.  **So move the RV**.

That is a showstopper.  You have to have that.  If this situation is being forced upon you by a property owner, then do a social hack: figure out who the local electrical inspector is, make a pretense to invite that family over to dinner, then "accidentally" have a breaker trip.

---

The other thing to watch for is **GFCI trips**.  If your breaker has a TEST button, it may be tripping on **ground faults** rather than overloads. A ground fault is when an appliance has an internal short circuit to ground - obviously that makes the appliance very dangerous *to you*, and the GFCI is protecting your life.  If that's the case, pay close attention to when it trips - if this happens when you plug in or use a particular appliance, then that appliance needs a trip to the repair shop. You can test that theory by plugging it into a kitchen or bathroom GFCI anywhere else.  *Don't plug it in anywhere there isn't a GFCI, obviously!*

---

To answer your *direct* question: The only way to do that is to move the RV subpanel to a new location which is accessible.  Fortunately if it's only an RV panel, that is pretty easy to do: you can use the *old* panel location as a splice box.  Connect the  two panels with EMT conduit, pull the necessary wires, and Bob's your uncle.  Leave breakers in the old junction box, just so you don't have holes in the front.

I looked into Eaton's BRRP and CLR breaker families, which provide remote *switching*, but they aren't a remote breaker reset, they just have an extra switch. You can throw the extra switch remotely, but cannot reset the breaker remotely. *I tried.*

Comment: Assuming the entire complex is miswired, not just OPs location the blowback from the 'accident' during dinner could end up being severe.  If renting short term, the OP should be prepared for the possibility of needing to relocate on little notice.